# Is there an option to copy the location with parameters in the Firefox DevTools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

My Firefox just got updated and my Firebug got uninstalled. I went back to install it. And after reading some comments on their page it turns out the option to copy the location with parameters is gone now.

Is there a different add-on or way to get the location parameters?

Comment: What do you mean with "location parameters"?

Comment: It outputted a url with the post parameters so the post could be done just with a url

Comment: I see. So, you mean the option [*Copy Location with Parameters*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Requests). It would have been clearer if you provided a link to the comments saying that location parameters are gone, the exact name of the option and/or a screenshot of it.

Comment: Yeah my bad, couldn't because it had been removed from my firefox and couldn't remember the exact name. Moving to firebug 2 worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug 2 still has the option *Copy Location with Parameters*:

[image: Option *Copy Location with Parameters* in Firebug's *Net* panel]

Though, because Firebug [does not work anymore](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/) once multi-process Firefox is enabled, you are probably actually using the Firefox DevTools.
Those tools do not provide the exact same option, though you can simply build your URL using two other options they offer ‒ *Copy URL* and *Copy POST Data*:

[image: *Copy URL* and *Copy POST Data* options in Firefox DevTools' *Network* panel]

You can also use the option [*Copy as cURL*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Copy_as_cURL), which allows you to execute the request via a command line using the [curl tool](http://curl.haxx.se/).